# Does Thunderbolt support a hub architecture?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hub, thunderbolt

I'd like to connect two monitors via a single Thunderbolt output. They are't Cinema Displays, so daisy chaining is not possible.

No hub-like device appears to exist that would allow multiple displays - even the recent docks all only have one monitor output port. It seems that I'm supposed to plug the dock in my MacBook, the external disk into the dock, and the second Display into the external disk, and the third display into the second display. This seems a bit insane.

Is there a technical reason why no one has decided to just create a hub? Does Thunderbolt not support a hub-architecture, or can we expect to see them at some point?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Multi-Stream Transport (MST) Hub, which replaces the need for a daisy-chain capable monitor. [They exist](http://www.guru3d.com/articles_pages/club3d_mst_hub_display_port_review,1.html) but good luck actually getting your hands on one. AMD especially has been hyping them up for years, and Club3D has apparently made one, but they're nowhere to be found. Also, watch out for other "DisplayPort hub" devices, as they will only split a single DP signal across displays.